# Bitrix фильтрация пользователей по дате регистрации

Tags: битрикс

Каким образом можно реализовать фильтрацию пользователей по дате регистрации, используя \Bitrix\Main\UserTable::getList ?
Способ из документации

```
 $arFilter = array(
   "DATE_REGISTER_1" => "21.12.2010 00:00:00",
   "DATE_REGISTER_2" => "21.12.2010 23:59:59",
   "ACTIVE" => 'Y',
);
```

не работает

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снят. Данное условие реализуется следующим образом:

```
$arFilter['><DATE_REGISTER'] = ['21.12.2010 00:00:00','21.12.2010 23:59:59'];
```